# Maven JgitFlow plugin Authentication Fail using SSH

Tags: git, maven, ssh, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I've clone the repository from stash using SSH and when I tried to create the feature branch using `mvn jgitflow:feature-start`, I'm facing the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:feature-start (default-cli) on project **************: Error starting feature: Error starting feature: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://URL.git: Auth fail -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:feature-start (default-cli) on project **************: Error starting feature: Error starting feature: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://URL.git: Auth fail
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

I'm executing this command in `Intellij terminal`. I've also created new `ssh-key` but still getting the same error. The ticket for this issue has already created on confluence [here](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/MJF-301) but the ticket logs aren't same. Furthermore I have clone the repository using `HTTP` and execute the same command and it works, it seems like this issue is occurring due to the recent changes in [git crypto](https://github.blog/2017-09-18-crypto-deprecation-notice-update-1/). If someone observe the same behaviour please notify me or please guide me if I'm missing anything.

Comment: was any resolution received ?

Comment: nope, ticket is still open

Comment: .There is another alternative plugin you can try" gitflow-maven-plugin" Source link: https://github.com/aleksandr-m/gitflow-maven-plugin Maven repository link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amashchenko.maven.plugin/gitflow-maven-plugin

Comment: Two years late to the party, but - are you just missing the `enableSshAgent` <configuration> option?

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jgit-flow/wiki/goals/release-start#!enablesshagent

Comment: Any news about this?

Answer (score 0):

We use GitHub Enterprise server which got upgraded from 3.4 to 3.6
Notification : https://github.blog/2022-06-28-improving-git-protocol-security-on-github-enterprise-server/
After our GitHub Server Crypto upgrade, I got the exact same exception when try to start release. I fixed this issue by setting up GITHub authentication using id/pwd instead of SSH. Within the Maven Parent Pom file there is plugin section for jgitflow-maven-plugin. In this there is a subsection , here we can set **enableSshAgent** as true or false. If true then SSH keys will be used to connect GitHub. If it is false then we have to provide username and password tag so I added that like below

```
<username>myuser</username>
<password>mypwd</password>
```

Afterwards I got known host prompt which I disabled by creating a config file within ~/.ssh

```
cat > config
Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

You need to ensure, the user which is trying to connect GitHub, should have proper ssh or credentials setup. When I try with SSH keys it has not worked with RSA,Ed25519, ECDSA. We raised with GIT Hub team and they provided below solution :

Some teams are using old OpenSSH clients that downgrade their updated keys.
Two methods that a team can take to ensure that their SSH keys are secure and ready for GitHub Enterprise Server 3.6 and above:

1. either generate new keys of the type ecdsa (this is supported in
   both OpenSSH and JSCH) for the impacted users — this is GitHub’s
   recommended approach
2. update the SSH clients to ones that translates the signature
   algorithm to rsa-sha2-512 for existing RSA keys

In my case ecdsa should have worked but it is using ssh keys from which location I was not able to determine. Hope above helps !!